# Ghost enemy AI that follows the player by copying the players position

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, queue, position

Okay, the plan is simple.
My plan is to make a simple AI that record every player.positions, and then follow the player by using those positions. So the AI will always be some steps behind the player. But when the player stops moving the AI should collide with player and then the player dies.

So my problem is when the player has been chased down by the AI, but it always runs out of position before the enemy AI is ever able to touch the player...

I used Queue for making a list of position, this was recommended by someone after I tried with List<>.
[Here's a video showing the problem](https://youtu.be/X4cS_emKLMA)

```
 public Transform player;
public Transform ghostAI;

public bool recording;
public bool playing;
Queue<Vector2> playerPositions;

public bool playerLeftRadius;




void Start()
{
    playerPositions = new Queue<Vector2>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (playerLeftRadius == true)
    {
        StartGhost();
    }

    Debug.Log(playerPositions.Count);


}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (playing == true)
    {
        PlayGhost();
    }
    else
    {
        Record();
    }
}


void Record()
{
    recording = true;
    playerPositions.Enqueue(player.transform.position);
}

void PlayGhost()
{

    ghostAI.transform.position = playerPositions.Dequeue();       
    
    
}

public void StartGhost()
{
    playing = true;
}

public void StopGhost()
{
    playing = false;
}


private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Player leaved the zone");
    playerLeftRadius = true;

}
```

How do improve it so it will be able to touch the player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the player touch the zone, method `OnTriggerExit2D()` is called. Then, method `PlayGhost()` is called and `Record()`  is stoped. So, the ghost can't record player.positions after player out zone.
You can remove `else` in method `FixedUpdate()` to fix it.

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (playing == true)
    {
        PlayGhost();
    }
    Record();
}
```